# Add text permanently when link is clicked in php

Tags: php, hyperlink

When you click the link I have you get redirected to a page that has this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['linkName'])) {
    echo "hello";
}
```

But this of course only shows "hello" when entering the page by clicking the link. What I want is that when the link has been clicked once the word "hello" will show even if you re-enter the page without clicking the link. How can I make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting `linkName` on link click ?

Comment: As a wild guess because you question isn't clear - you may want to store the value into a $_SESSION variable i.e. $_SESSION['linkname'] = $_GET['linkname']; See the documentation for details https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @jeff I will try that!

Comment: @AmbrishPathak yes

Comment: @Agnes99 See if the answer i have posted below works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maintaining state, session could be used so, once a session has been set up it can be used again and again until it expires (default is 24 mins, controlled by php.ini)

By this approach you may do it like:

```
<a href="foo.php?action=login">Login</a>
```

When the user is redirected to foo.php

Check for a session if it exists echo "hello" else create a new session

```
if (isset($_SESSION['linkName'])) {
    echo "hello";
} else {
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $_SESSION['linkName'] = $_GET['action'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove isset from your code if you want users to display hello without getting redirected or entering in to page directly.